# how to completely disable pagefile use wmic

Tags: windows-7, batch, pagefile, wmic

Hi I am trying to create a batch file to disable the page file on windows 7, is there any wmic command will do this? I know I should be able to use

"wmic pagefileset delete"

however this always give me the error no instance(s) available, any example would be great, many thanks!

Comment: Why can't you just set the pagefile to zero?

Answer (score 5):

When you want to change your page file settings you need to first turn the automatic pagefile off and after that make a new pagefile with your own defined settings. In the Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) the automatic pagefile and the set page file have different aliasses:
The automatically managed pagefile can be 'managed' through the pagefile alias. Since everything is managed automatically there's only a view command you can use in the following way:

```
wmic pagefile
```

or

```
wmic pagefile list /format:list
```

(I prefer the last one since it has output in a more humanly viewable format)

The selfmanaged pagefile can be managed through the pagefileset alias. Before you can set a pagefile however, you need to disable the automatic pagefile. The command for this is:

```
wmic computersystem where name="%computername%" set AutomaticManagedPagefile=False
```

After that you can use the pagefileset command to set a pagefile, to create a pagefile, to delete a pagefile... basically all the stuff you want to do with a pagefile. For instance: to create a pagefile to replace the C:\pagefile.sys with a fixed size of 2048 Megabyte, (I don't know why the Step-by-Step guide mentions bytes... the command obviously measures in MegaBytes) simply type:

```
wmic pagefileset where name="C:\\pagefile.sys" set InitialSize=2048,MaximumSize=2048
```

After setting the pagefile yourself, you can check its settings with:

```
wmic pagefileset
```

or

```
wmic pagefileset list /format:list
```

(Obviously I prefer the latter one again)

To make the settings take effect you need to reboot.

[Source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/708da424-3a7c-404d-8f54-f989ed62d323/command-for-changeing-the-page-file?forum=winservercore)

Comment: after disabling the `AutomaticManagedPagefile` you remove the pagefile with the following command : `wmic pagefileset where name="C:\\pagefile.sys" delete`