# Unable to disable pagefile and thus unable to change device letter under Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, pagefile, disk-management

I just found one of the most weird bugs I have seen in Windows. I needed to disable the pagefile in one of my partitions so I could change its letter. However, the dialog box is missing the set button, and seen as cutted in half, as shown in the image below.

[image]

Some background info that might be usefull: This is in Windows 10 Pro and the install is not fresh. Windows is installed in a hard drive which was from an old laptop. This hard drive was simply removed from the laptop and put in a desktop.

I've already tried resizing the window with a program called ResizeEnable without success. I tried to use command line to disable pagefile (using basically this question: [how to completely disable pagefile use wmic](https://superuser.com/questions/952599/how-to-completely-disable-pagefile-use-wmic)) without success - I get a "no instance available" when trying to manage the pagefile, even after creating a new one. I managed to extract the file "SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe" from Win10 install DVD and tried to replace the one under C:\Windows\System32 with it. Windows would not let me do it and running the file from the desktop just led me to the same bug.

I am now out of ideas. I thought about changing the windows drive letters from Linux (I have an Ubuntu live CD and can burn a new one if needed). However all answers I found said it was impossible. So, I am accepting anything that allow me to disable pagefiles or other methods that allow me to change the device letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ### [Modify Pagefile Configuration from the Command Line](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-server/modify-pagefile-configuration-command-line)
>
> **Q: How can I change the pagefile configuration from the commandline?**
>
> **A:** This is very useful on Server Core systems where no graphical interface is required. Here I create a new pagefile on the P: volume
>   and delete the old pagefile:
>
> ```
> wmic pagefileset create name="P:\pagefile.sys"
>
> wmic pagefileset where name="P:\\pagefile.sys" set InitialSize=2048,MaximumSize=2048
>
> wmic pagefileset where name="C:\\pagefile.sys" delete
> ```
>
> Reboot the machine for the change to take effect. To list the
>   pagefiles, use the command below:
>
> ```
> wmic pagefile list /format:list
> ```
>
> <sub>[source](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-server/modify-pagefile-configuration-command-line)</sub>

---

Comment: It worked wonderfully. I was using two backslashes instead of a single one in the create statement. I am puzzled why microsoft choosed such inconsistent and not intuitive way of doing things. But very much thank you!